# iPhone UIActivityIndicatorView not starting or stopping

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

When I call startAnimating on a UIActivityIndicatorView, it doesn't start.  Why is this?

[This is a blog-style self-answered question.  The solution below works for me, but, maybe there are others that are better?]

Comment: You might want to make it clear you are posting a blog style self-answered question.

Answer (score 16):

If you write code like this:

```
- (void) doStuff
{
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    ...lots of computation...
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

You aren't giving the UI time to actually start and stop the activity indicator, because all of your computation is on the main thread.  One solution is to call startAnimating in a separate thread:

```
- (void) threadStartAnimating:(id)data {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)doStuff
{ 
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    ...lots of computation...
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Or, you could put your computation on a separate thread, and wait for it to finish before calling stopAnimation.

Comment: does this method starts a new thread..??? if yes then where and how to stop it..??

Comment: This would give weird errors (or crash) since `startAnimating` HAS to be called on main thread. The second option of doing the computation on another thread is the correct approach.

Answer (score 12):

I usually do:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self performSelector:@selector(lotsOfComputation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];

...

- (void)lotsOfComputation {
    ...
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same, with the difference that I use -(void)performBlock:(void (^)(void))block afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay; from  http://forrst.com/posts/Delayed_Blocks_in_Objective_C-0Fn When I specify 0.0, no progress indicator is shown, and 0.01 is the time between flashes of a 100Hz monitor.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite useful. But one thing that is missing in the answer post is , every thing that takes long time need to be perform in separate thread not the UIActivityIndicatorView. This way it won't stop responding to UI interface.

```
    - (void) doLotsOFWork:(id)data {
    //  do the work here.
}

    -(void)doStuff{
    [activityIndicator startAnimating]; 
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doLotsOFWork:) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; 
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: I would go with this one. It is the best explanation out there. One fix though is I would move the call to stop animating the indicator in the method that you have detached. It will stop the animation once the method is complete.

Answer (score 1):

All UI elements require to be on main thread

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startIndicator) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

then:

```
-(void)startIndicator{
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If needed, swift 3 version:

```
func doSomething() {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        //do some processing intensive stuff
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry seems like I went through my code being blind.

I've ended the Indicator like this:

```
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
activityIndicator = nil;
```

So after one run, the activityIndicator has been removed completely.