# UIAcitivity Indicator with UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am developing an app where the user will get to confirm some action via `UIAlertView`, if he confirms, I call a method that handles the operation, then I prepare to pop the view I am in to go back to another view after the method has been called.

I want to show `UIActivityIndicatorView` if the user presses confirm for as long as it takes to execute the method and go to that other view. I used `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` in the proper location, but i never get to see the UI `UIActivityIndicatorView` shown, not for a sec.

I guess its related to some UI issues due to `UIAlertView`, not sure if I am correct though. I just need a clue on how to use `UIActivityIndicatorView` properly for a method execution time.

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 1) {

        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

        ContactsTableViewController *contactTableView = [self getContactsTVC];

        [contactTableView applyActionOnCells];

        // doing some setup before poping off to the root view controller of my nav controller 

        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

        // then go to rootViewController
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some relevant code.

Comment: You can also check out `MBProgressHUD` if you're having issues with implementing your own `UIActivityIndicatorView`

Comment: Please edit your question and show us some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain, but try to comment out the `stopAnimating` call and see if it shows up.

If that helps, `applyActionOnCells` probably blocks your main thread (where all UI stuff also happens) and the indicator never has a chance to show up before you hide it again.

In that case, try do the `applyActionOnCells` call in the background:

```
if(buttonIndex == 1) {
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    __block typeof(self) bself = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        ContactsTableViewController *contactTableView = [bself getContactsTVC];
        [contactTableView applyActionOnCells];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [bself.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

            // then go to rootViewController
            [bself.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

Edit: see also [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850186/iphone-uiactivityindicatorview-not-starting-or-stopping).

Comment: Works like a charm.
So what i learn from this is anything related to UI must be executed on the main thread? and if its not happening then the main thread is busy executing something else. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (An official quote is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikit_framework/Introduction/Introduction.html))